# Open Video file in VLC through Python

Tags: python, video, vlc

```
import subprocess
import os
print os.path.exists("C:/Users/Dhruv/Desktop/Motivation/RiseShine.mp4") 
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe","C:/Users/Dhruv/Desktop/Motivation/RiseShine.mp4"])
```

The code above is to open a video file in VLC player using python. The VLC player opens up, but does not run the video. I have checked the video location, it is correct.
Can somebody tell me how to make this work?

Comment: any error messages? This worked here so i'm not able to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me (Python 3.4):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe","\\E:\Movies\\" + title + '.mp4'])
```

The video tested was definitely in mp4 format, btw.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help, you should specify a file stream as follows:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe","file:\\\Users\Dhruv\Desktop\Motivation\RiseShine.mp4"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe","C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\videos\\example.mp4"])
```

The difference is in the way to put the: ' \ ' , ' // '

Answer (score 0):

Raw Strings and Back Slashes are your friend here:

```
path = r"C:\Users\Dhruv\Desktop\Motivation\RiseShine.mp4"
print(path)
```

Output, a correctly formatted for the command-line string:

```
'C:\\Users\\Dhruv\\Desktop\\Motivation\\RiseShine.mp4'
```