# How to add to VLC playlist queue using Python subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, vlc

I am trying to use the Python 2.7 `subprocess` library to programmatically add songs to the VLC player queue.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188114/open-video-file-in-vlc-through-python) and [here](http://gotoanswer.com/?q=creating%20a%20playlist%20from%20listbox%20selection%20and%20playing%20it%20using%20VLC%3F), I am able to launch VLC Player and play a song (or queue songs from the outset);

```
from subprocess import Popen
vlcpath = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe'
musicpath1 = r'path\to\song1.mp3'
musicpath2 = r'path\to\song2.mp3'
p = Popen([vlcpath,musicpath1]) # launch VLC and play song
p = Popen([vlcpath,musicpath1,musicpath2]) # launch VLC and play/queue songs
```

The problem is that I do not know the entire queue playlist at launch. I want to be able to add songs to the queue of the VLC process already running. How do I accomplish this, please?

From [here](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=65006), I think the appropriate command line entry is:

```
vlc.exe --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue "2.wmv"
```

But I do not know the syntax to execute this in `subprocess`. I tried a couple of things, but couldn't get either to work:

- calling [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) again (opens a new process)
- calling [p.communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) (I thought this is how to enter stdin commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the command: `vlc.exe --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue "2.wmv"`
 using `subprocess` module on Windows:

```
from subprocess import Popen

cmd = 'vlc.exe --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue "2.wmv"'
p = Popen(cmd) # start and forget
assert not p.poll() # assert that it is started successfully
```

To wait for the command to finish:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(cmd) # start, wait until it is done, raise on non-zero exit status
```

---

> But how do I run that command a second time on the same p process?
>   Your code starts a new instance of VLC, rather than running that on
>   top of the p that was already open. I found that if I run the `vlc.exe --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue "2.wmv"` command multiple times manually (in a command prompt window), it correctly launches vlc (the
>   first time) and then adds to queue (on subsequent calls). So I think I
>   just need to be able to run the code you suggested multiple times "on
>   top of itself"

Each `Popen()` *starts a new process*. Each time you run the command manually in the command-line it *starts a new process*. It might be upto the current vlc configuration on your system whether it keeps multiple vlc instances or you are running a different command (different command-line arguments).

Comment: thank you. But how do I run that command a *second time* on the same `p` process? Your code starts a new instance of VLC, rather than running that on top of the `p` that was already open. I found that if I run the `vlc.exe --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue "2.wmv"` command multiple times manually (in a command prompt window), it correctly launches vlc (the first time) and then adds to queue (on subsequent calls). So I think I just need to be able to run the code you suggested multiple times "on top of itself".

Comment: Thanks! All this time I was avoiding starting new processes because I somehow assumed the command line would operate on the same one. Anyways, based on your comment, I dug around in the VLC preferences and found that everything works as expected now that I have enabled a couple of options: `Allow only one instance` and `Enqueue items into playlist in one instance mode`. Still not sure why this queueing behaviour worked natively from the command line, but not from Python subprocess - I thought they do the same thing.